# SQL Server Query to find best quantity division

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that stores products of varying pack sizes. I want to do a select query to choose the best combinations of product to select the minimum amount of products for a given order.

The query must check pack size and quantity available to produce the best results.

| Pid | Packsize | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 |

Examples
Order  = 5

| Pid | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

Examples
Order  = 7

| Pid | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

**Out of stock examples**

| Pid | Packsize | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 |

Examples
Order  = 5

| Pid | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

Examples
Order  = 7

| Pid | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |

Comment: This seems to be a [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) which is NP-Complete, and therefore going to be exponentially difficult to do without heuristics, dynamic programming and memoization. I'd venture to say that T-SQL is probably the wrong tool. Do you have any code so far, because this is a problem that is not really solvable in a single [so] answer (at least for any reasonable amount of rows, for a small number you can just brute-force)

Answer (score 0):

For all those that have this problem in the future I have come up with a solution.

```
--CREATE TABLE [dbo].[item_tbl](
--[pid] [int] NULL,
--[packsize] [int] NULL,
--[qty] [int] NULL
--) ON [PRIMARY]
--GO
--INSERT [dbo].[item_tbl] ([pid], [packsize], [qty]) VALUES (1, 5, 1)
--GO
--INSERT [dbo].[item_tbl] ([pid], [packsize], [qty]) VALUES (2, 3, 4)
--GO
--INSERT [dbo].[item_tbl] ([pid], [packsize], [qty]) VALUES (3, 2, 4)
--GO
--INSERT [dbo].[item_tbl] ([pid], [packsize], [qty]) VALUES (4, 1, 4)


if object_id('tempdb..#tmpord') is not null

    drop table #tmpord

CREATE TABLE #tmpord(
    [pid] [int] NULL,
    [packsize] [int] NULL,
    [qty] [int] NULL)


declare @tqty int

declare @qty int
declare @pid int
declare @pkt int
declare @stock int

set @tqty=10

DECLARE @Counter INT 
SET @Counter=0
WHILE ( @Counter < @tqty)
BEGIN
set @qty =@tqty-@Counter
set @pkt= (select max(packsize) from item_tbl where (@qty / packsize)>0)
set @pid=(select pid from item_tbl where packsize=@pkt)
declare @os int
INSERT INTO #tmpord
           ([pid]
           ,[packsize]
           ,[qty])
     VALUES
           (@pid
           ,@pkt
           ,1)




    SET @Counter  = @Counter +  @pkt
END
select pid,packsize,  qty from #tmpord

select pid, Count(*) as PacksRequired from #tmpord
Group by pid
```